# Fixing the same height for multipart rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, multipart-node

I am not able to fix the height of both parts of a (vertical) two-part rectangle to the same height. As a result, the arrow to the box on the right is not aligned with the middle line. I have been reading but have not been able to resolve it. Is there a way? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{
arrows %
,positioning %
,shapes%
,shapes.multipart%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle split, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, align=center] (box1) {Application \nodepart[text width=3cm]{two} GFS Client};
\node[rectangle,draw, align=center, right=3.5cm of box1] (box2) {Master};

\draw[->] (box1) -- (box2) node[midway, above] ( ) {Get chunk location};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Here is what comes out:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, both parts of multipart rectangle don't have similar height, because `Application` has a decendant part (`p`) which is not present in `GFS Client`. You can force them to be equal inserting a `\strut` command in both texts.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{
arrows %
,positioning %
,shapes%
,shapes.multipart%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle split, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, align=center] (box1) {Application\strut \nodepart[text width=3cm]{two} GFS Client\strut};
\node[rectangle,draw, align=center, right=3.5cm of box1] (box2) {Master};

\draw[->] (box1) -- (box2) node[midway, above] ( ) {Get chunk location};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this -- I now learned another way to do this.

Comment: @ozsu I was actually also thinking about using `\strut` but was deciding against it because this wastes some space. That's why I was using a `\vphantom{p}`....

Answer (score 3):

I would actually not try to make the node parts equally high (even though this can be done), but just let the arrow start at the `text split`.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{
arrows %
,positioning %
,shapes%
,shapes.multipart%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle split, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, align=center] (box1) {Application \nodepart[text width=3cm]{two} GFS Client};
\node[rectangle,draw, align=center, right=3.5cm of box1.text split east] (box2) {Master};

\draw[->] (box1.text split east) -- (box2) node[midway, above] ( ) {Get chunk location};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But if you really need the heights to coincide, just call a phantom.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\usetikzlibrary{
arrows %
,positioning %
,shapes%
,shapes.multipart%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[rectangle split, draw, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,
align=center] (box1) {Application \nodepart[text width=3cm]{two} \vphantom{p}GFS Client};
\node[rectangle,draw, align=center, right=3.5cm of box1] (box2) {Master};

\draw[->] (box1) -- (box2) node[midway, above] ( ) {Get chunk location};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, many thanks. I did not know either option and am very glad to learn.

Comment: defining text width for node part at vertical split rectangles has no sense. in it all parts have equal width ...

Comment: @Zarko I agree, thanks, didn't look carefully. On the other hand, it really does not hurt here either.